# Parsing HTML Structure

Tags: html, actionscript-3, parsing, html-parsing

I need to parse an html source in order to obtain some links...

Let's assume we have:

```
<html>
<head>....</head>
<body>
  <div ....>
   ....
     <a href="link0">
     <div class="class1">
       <a href="link1">
      </div>
     <a href="link2">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I only want the `link1` which is a child of a `div` with class `class1`

I really can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [tutorial on working with XML in ActionScript](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/).

Comment: Note that HTML is not guaranteed to be XML compatible - eg closing tags are not always required. This may work in a controlled environment, but should not be used for general purpose web page parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about actionscript, but I'd suggest you not to try and re-invent the wheel. There must be some XML parser available for actionscript. Use it. For starters, refer to [W3CSchools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp). I repeat - use a parser, don't write it yourself unless you really have a very string reason to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Easy...

In ActionScript, you need to get your html source as a string. Then you need to look for that div using regular expressions.

```
var s:String="my html source";
var regex:RegExp=/<div.*?class="class1".*?>.*?<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/gi;

var o:Array=regex.exec(s);

trace(o[1]); //Gives you the href
trace(o[2]); //Gives you the anchortext
```

Comment: @32bitkid...for example??? The ONLY way it will break is if the html format changes (in which case all other methods will break

Comment: There are a bunch of structures that will trick a simple regex into a false positive that will not "fool" a real parser. Anytime you are trying to enforce a parent/child relationship between nodes, a regex is a "Bad Idea&trade;". Your regex doesn't look understand parent/child, all its looking for is a token followed by another token. It should be obvious how this will break.